# Is it possible to have a .NET route that maps to the same place as a directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I'm building a CMS using WebForms on .NET 4.0 and have the following route that allows URLs like www.mysite.com/about to be mapped to the Page.aspx page, which looks up the dynamic content.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("page", "{name}", "~/Page.aspx");
```

The problem is that I have a couple of folders in my project that are interfering with possible URLs. For example, I have a folder called "blog" where I store pages related to handling blog functionality, but if someone creates a page for their site called "blog" then navigating to www.mysite.com/blog gets the following error:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You
>   do not have permission to view this
>   directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

Other similar URLs route correctly, but I think because .NET is identifying /blog as a physical location on the server it is denying directory access.  Is there a way to tell IIS / .NET to only look for physical files instead of files and folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like IIS is denying you access to the actual folder.

By default Routing is supposed to honor the file system. Though this can be turned off.

Comment: How do you turn it off, it is it a setting in IIS or the web.config?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx has Routing documentation.  Here is the specific link for that feature 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx

Comment: Okay, that was what I was looking for. I just had to Ignore some routes to keep the system from processing my .aspx files on disk.  If anyone else needs them, I used 

routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });

from Phil Haack's post: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx